# Multithreading vs Multiprocessing basics

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I am trying to understand the difference between the two.So far what i know:

- Every process has its own memory space
- Each thread shares the same memory space as its parent process

What i need to know:

1. If i run 10 processes(let's say using python's multiprocessing module),which
   scheduling algorithm will be used? How would context switch take place ?
2. Let's say i am running the above on my Windows Quad core machine,does it imply that at a time only 4 processes can be served ?
3. How many processes out of 10 go to Ready queue(waiting to be scheduled on a core/CPU) ?
4. How many processes out of 10 go to Job queue(list of processes that reside on mass storage/secondary storage and await main memory allocation) ?
5. Suppose instead of Multiprocess i use Python's Multithreading module -what would be the answer for above 4 questions ?